# this orientation correlation equation is not a 'correlation'?

Tags: correlation, circular-statistics

I have been reading this paper studying the interaction of fishes.

There are two fishes, whose positions over time are given. This means that we can compute for the velocity (vector) for each time step. (Speed with direction.)

Here is an excerpt from the paper:

"The orientation correlation is then computed by taking the dot product of the velocity vectors of the two fish at successive time intervals:

$$ C_0(dt) = \left < v_1(t) \cdot v_2(t+dt)\right >$$

where the average is taken over all pairs of fish that are tracked for time $dt$. This quantity will be $1$ if the fish are always perfectly aligned, $-1$ if in the opposite direction and $0$ is not correlated."

My question is:

1. I do not understand the part where the average "is taken over all pairs of fish". How do I do that?
2. Also, I am not sure how this will have a product ranging from $-1$ to $1$ since the velocities can be more than unity.

Comment: Can you please link to the paper?

Comment: http://www.pnas.org/content/108/46/18720.full.pdf?with-ds=yes

Comment: It is page 1 (Supporting Information), equation [S2]